# Providing oauth credentials from ios client and app engine endpoint

Tags: java, ios, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working on app engine endpoints (back end), i have created credentials for ios, web application and others, client id and Client secret are generated (same id are added as part of endpoint code ). Now i assume app engine endpoint requests are authorized by oauth from the IOS and when call it from api-explorer. My questions are

1. When endpoints are tested through api-explorer, without client id i am able to get success response. Is it something i need to do, so that oauth is the first level of security always ?

> ```
>    @Api(name = "myapp", version = "v1", description = "myapp cloud-endpoint", 
> clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID})
> public class YourFirstAPI {
> ```

2. How to give client id and Client secret from IOS client while consuming app engine endpoints ?

Please help  me on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Endpoints auth is optional. If you need to require auth, currently you need to inject the User parameter into your API methods and check them manually. For example,

   `public void apiMethod(User user) {
     if (user == null) {
       throw new UnauthorizedException();
     }
     ...
   }`
2. I suggest you check out the [Rest iOS client docs](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki).